# Verification Email is not sent upon User's email address change

Tags: ios, email, parse-platform

Our app on Parse.com for iOS allows our users to change their registered email address.
When an user changes her address, a verification email should be sent to her new address, but the mail is not sent.

When we look at the DataStore, we can see that the "email" field is updated to the new one, and 'emailVerified' field is set to 'false'.

When we change the same user's 'email' field directly from the DataStore, the verification mail arrives shortly to the user.

So I suspect this must be some bug in the SDK or Parse.com?
Anyone experiencing this?